# Right Exoplayer Uri

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I downloaded a simple `Exoplayer` example (this link: [github example](https://github.com/ayalus/ExoPlayer-2-Example))

And it works perfectly with the uri that is set into it, but when I change to the video a want to play, nothing happens. I guess the `Uri` i'm trying to set is not right. How can I make this video play correctly?

Here is the class with the simple class. The `Uri` lines are commented:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VideoRendererEventListener {


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private TextView resolutionTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    resolutionTextView = new TextView(this);
    resolutionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resolution_textView);

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
    simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(  this);
    simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);

    simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();

    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    //THIS WORKS!
    Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://54.255.155.24:1935//Live/_definst_/amlst:sweetbcha1novD235L240P/playlist.m3u8");

    //THIS IS THE ONE I WANT TO PLAY!
    //Uri mp4VideoUri =Uri.parse("http://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/April/58ffdcf9_9-final-product-brownies/9-final-product-brownies.mp4");


    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "exoplayer2example"), bandwidthMeterA);

    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

    MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
    final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);

    player.prepare(loopingSource);

    player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onTimelineChanged...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onTracksChanged...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onLoadingChanged...isLoading:"+isLoading);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPlayerStateChanged..." + playbackState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onRepeatModeChanged...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPlayerError...");
            player.stop();
            player.prepare(loopingSource);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {
            Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPositionDiscontinuity...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Listener-onPlaybackParametersChanged...");
        }
    });

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.setVideoDebugListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onVideoEnabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoDecoderInitialized(String decoderName, long initializedTimestampMs, long initializationDurationMs) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoInputFormatChanged(Format format) {

}

@Override
public void onDroppedFrames(int count, long elapsedMs) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged ["  + " width: " + width + " height: " + height + "]");
    resolutionTextView.setText("RES:(WxH):"+width+"X"+height +"\n           "+height+"p");
}

@Override
public void onRenderedFirstFrame(Surface surface) {

}

@Override
public void onVideoDisabled(DecoderCounters counters) {

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStop()...");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStart()...");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.v(TAG, "onResume()...");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v(TAG, "onPause()...");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy()...");
    player.release();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HlsMediaSource** is used for **Adaptive Streaming** videos. The video link inside example is for live streaming. For other video formats like `mp4, ogg, 3gp, wav` etc, use **ExtractorMediaSource**.

Here is the code sample, to handle both (if required) -

```
final LoopingMediaSource loopingSource;
Uri mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse(uri);
if (uri.contains("m3u8")) {
     MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 3, null, null);
     loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);
}else {
     MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
     loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);
}
```

here is the [ExoPlayer Developer guide](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html) for more info.

Comment: nit: actually, HLS can be VOD as well not only live.  It's maybe more correct to say "HLS is for adaptive streaming"

Answer (score 1):

You're using an `HlsMediaSource` here: `new HlsMediaSource(mp4VideoUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);`. But you really want to use an `ExtractorMediaSource`.

More information can be found [here](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#mediasource).

`.m3u8` is an HLS file and `.mp4`, `.wav`, etc would need the `ExtractorMediaSource`.